# StreamBuilder, Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod, stream-builder, flutter-streambuilder

I'm making a Reddit clone and I've just finished the chat part. Everytime I send a message to someone, the database is structured in this way: users/$userid/chats/$receiverid/messages/$allmessagesmodels. Now I want to display the list of all the recent chats with a StreamBuilder, but it seems there is no data.

```
Stream<List<UserModel>> getUserChats() {
  final currentId = authInstance.currentUser!.uid;

  return firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc(currentId).collection("chats").snapshots().map((docs) => docs.docs.map((doc) => UserModel.fromMap(doc.data())).toList(),);

}
```

And this is the chat part where I use the StreamBuilder.

```
class ChatTab extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ChatTab({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ChatTab> createState() => _ChatTabState();
}

class _ChatTabState extends ConsumerState<ChatTab> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: secondaryBgColor,
      body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).getUserChats(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasError) {
              log(snapshot.error.toString());
              return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),);
            }

            return SizedBox();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm sure that the chats exist and the database structure is right, but I don't see nothing, If i try to log the data, it prints me: "[log] []" . I also tried to log the snapshot.error, but there is no error.

Comment: tried to `print(currentId)`? is it a valid id?

Comment: Yes I printed it and it's correct

Comment: and what do you see if you do `firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc(currentId).collection("chats").snapshots().listen(print)` (without using `StreamBuilder`)?

Comment: Can you provide me an example? I've never used the .listen method

Comment: i already did in my previous comment: `firestoreInstance.collection("users").doc(currentId).collection("chats").snapshots().listen(print)`

Comment: I/flutter (17169): Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'

Comment: Btw maybe i will explain myself better. What i need to do is getting all the documents ids from "users/userid/chats/" where the document ids are the receiver uids. Then, I have to get all the receivers data from the uids I got to display them in my screen